# Setting a fixed GridView width on the first column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a GridView that is connected to a Dictionary<>. I want to set a maximum width only for the first column. I know that DataGrid.ColumnWidth sets a static columnwidth, but that's for all the columns. How can I define specific width for specific columns?

[image: Gridview]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
DataGrid.Columns[0].Width = 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridTemplateColumn template:

```
`<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300" Header="Test">
//Your control (TextBlock)
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>`
```

Comment: The columns are programatically added using, not through the XAML, so this won't work.

Comment: In this case you can subscribe to event AutoGeneratedColumns of DataGrid (`<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid" AutoGeneratedColumns="dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns" />`) and in event handler change column width:
 `private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             dataGrid.Columns[1].Width = 300;
        }` (change second column width to 300)